# Install the latest possible version if the specified version is not found

Tags: python-3.x, pip, requirements.txt

I have a requirements.txt with over 200 libraries.
When I install many libraries version not found.

How can I try to install libraries with specified version from requirements.txt and if it not found, then install the latest possible version?

Comment: It's also possible to get that "version not found" error when the package is not anymore compatible with your OS and environment.